An easy method for estimating Range of Motion (ROM) from IMU data
I have a dataset of IMU recordings that have captured Accelerometer XYZ, Gyroscope XYZ and Quaternions, while people were performing arm exercises (e.g., raising arm to the side, out to the front, and so on).
My goal is to determine, given a sample set of exercise repetitions, some estimation of range of motion quality as a single number output (e.g., an average of 6 repetitions in the set). This would be, how far the angle from the resting position has changed, I guess.
I am new to this area, but I understand that I will need to use either quaternion or gyro data (not sure what the benefits are of each).
For instance, when doing arm raises, the sensor rotates around its Y-Axis. However, this could be over differing levels of time (they do it slow or fast) and I'm not sure how this would impact the data, and if quaternion would therefore be a better fit for this.
I need some guidance on the approach towards calculating this number given the data I have access to. Ideally, the most simple approach that provides as accurate a number as possible.
